# Get only a specific address using getifaddrs

Tags: c, networking

I'm using [`getifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) in my program. 
I want to analyze just the `br-lan` but only the last one.

To do so, I'm parsing the `ifa` and I store in a `char*` the address whenever `ifa->ifa_name` is equal to `br-lan`.

Problem, overriding my `char*` for each `br-lan` is gluttonous. How can I get only the last one without any parsing?

Comment: Is always `br-lan` the last one?

Comment: @Silveris yes it is

Comment: You could try to get the last one based on the size of the list and the size of an element of this list. You will have to loop through your list once to know its size though.

Comment: @Silveris thought about it but I can iterate like `current->next` but not the other way

Comment: Then save a pointer to the first element.

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389904/total-size-of-a-linked-list-in-c might help you to know the size of your list :)

Comment: what are `br-lan` and `getifaddrs`? why don't add the related tags?

Comment: Have you measured the cost?  Are you sure it's significant?  It'd almost be surprising to find that it was measurable, let alone actually a significant part of your program's runtime.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using this for an IoT project, override and copy each time a buffer is definitely not the best idea

Comment: That's not the question I asked.  I asked "have you measured the cost?".  If you haven't measured, you're guessing that it's expensive.  I'm guessing that this is not the bottleneck in your program.  And if it is a cost, why are you reevaluating the `getifaddrs()` so often?  Are you sure you need to do it multiple times per second?  If you aren't doing it multiple times a second, the cost is negligible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler wasn't my question either, it was about how can I directly get the last occurence, not 'is the cost negligible', but thanks

Comment: You can't.  So you have to step through the list. You can decide not to copy until you've been through the list, keeping just a pointer to the last relevant entry, then do the copying that worries you. I think you're worrying about the wrong thing — or you have not indicated the reason why you're concerned about this and why it is a real problem to do it the straight-forward way. The cost of the work done by `getifaddrs()` itself probably outweighs the work you're doing analyzing its results. The design of the interface — a linked list instead of an array — precludes what you would like to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, it's very helpful, I'll try to lighten the other parts then